# How to reuse a function while maintaining functionally but changing styling

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

Good day!

I'm a new React Developer currently working on a project where I want to reuse a function (called renderPost) that is styled a certain way on one page, but I want to call the function with different styling in another page.

```
const styling = {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: "column",
  borderWidth: 2,
  borderColor: Colors.grey400,
  borderRadius: 10,
  maxWidth: 750,
  width: "100%",
  alignSelf: "center",
};
export const renderPost = (post, userID) => {
  if (post.item) {
    post = post.item;
  } 
return (
    <View
      role="listitem"
      className="ui items"
      key={post.id}
      style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
    >
      <View
        className="ui item"
        style={[styling, Platform.OS != "web" ? { width: "90%" } : null]}
      >
```

Is there a way for me to call the renderPost function in a new component while maintaining its functionality but changing the "styling" const to have different styles? I tried passing a styles as prop in renderPost but that got very messy and confusing so I'm looking for a neater way to do things.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React sharing method across components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604179/react-sharing-method-across-components)

Comment: Maybe use a Context object to share the styles across pages instead of passing it through props.

Comment: @figbar thanks, I'll look into that!

Comment: You can pass a different style as an argument.